# HAProxy doesn't support SSL

Tags: linux, load, load-balancing, haproxy

Is there a way around using HAProxy with SSL? I know the new version is supposed to support that, but how stable is that? Are there any things I need to consider for setting up a load balancer with https?

Comment: should not this question be in SuperUser?

Answer (score 1):

i use it for ssl.  config it as tcp.  and use the ssl-hello-chk.

Answer (score 0):

Come on, it is in development, nobody will guarantee you that it's safe and stable enough to use it in production.

Development version is stable enough for me, i've been using it for a while. However, as i said, it is your decision to test it, use it, or trust someone else. You can try alternatives like pound and wait for the stable relase. If you are sure that stable release will be much more safer :)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, 1.5-dev17 + latest fixes seems reasonably stable, which does not mean there are no bugs left, of course. Alternatively, if you really need not to worry about tracking bug fixes, you could go for a commercially supported version (or even an appliance) which involves a fork of a development version with all fixes backported.